# Setting a field in django admin that is unchangeable

Tags: python, django, django-admin, admin

I'm currently developing a Django app that is used by multiple gas stations. I have a station model with every station having it's own object. Each station will have its own account and can only modify values for their own station.

I am making a report to be submitted via Django admin, but I want to set the "station" field to their station name, where they can't view other station names nor change the selection to the other stations. In the admin.py, this is what I have (the report is called Shipment), the field in question is called station.

```
class ShipmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #readonly_fields = ['station'] <- I thought this would work but it removes the value I set if user = manager
   
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(ShipmentAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if str(request.user) == 'manager':
            form.base_fields['station'].initial = 'Texaco'
        else:
            form.base_fields['station'].initial = 'Exxon'
```

Please let me know if you guys know how to fix this. Basically if the user is manager, set the station value to "Texaco", else set it to "Exxon", and don't allow that field to be changed. Thanks!

Comment: Can you move this logic to the ShipmentAdmin __init__ method ?

Comment: @user1464664 I'm not exactly sure how to go by doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Initial values will always be overwritten if the field has a value saved in db.

One way to do this would be to dynamically render readonly fields:

```
class ShipmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('station',) # exclude original station field

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if str(request.user) == 'manager':
            return self.readonly_fields + ('station_value_for_manager',)
        else:
            return self.readonly_fields + ('station_value_for_everyone_else',)

    def station_value_for_manager(self, instance):
        return 'Texaco'
    station_value_for_manager.short_description = 'Station'

    def station_value_for_everyone_else(self, instance):
        return "Exxon"
    station_value_for_everyone_else.short_description = 'Station'
```